# How to get real time balance in php

Tags: php, mysql

For example I have a variable $opening_balance = 5000; Now more transactions are taking place with debit and credit and I want to fetch data from database and want to print real time balance at the end of each row. Following is is an example what I want exactly in my results.

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Sr No. | Description | Debit  | Credit | Balance |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1.     | Debit       | 500    |  -     | 4500    |
| 1.     | Credit      | -      |  1000  | 5500    |
| 1.     | Debit       | 200    |  -     | 5300    |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Following is my code: -

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM patty_cash WHERE month(date) = '11' AND year(date) = '2020' ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   extract($row);
   $newBalance = $opening_balance + $credit - $debit; 
   echo "<tr>
          <td>$sr_no</td>
          <td>$description</td>
          <td>$debit</td>
          <td>$credit</td>
          <td>$newBalance</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

But I am not getting accurate balance. Please suggest what to do to get accurate balance.

Comment: Can you show the output you are getting.

Comment: Set `$newBalance = $opening_balance;` before the `while` and update the `$newBalance = ` line in the `while` to read like `$newBalance = $newBalance + $credit - $debit;` so that it takes into account the previous changes. Can also be shortened slightly. Currently you appear to be doing 5000 + credit - debit on every row.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `extract($row)` like that. Specially when you have `SELECT * FROM` since it's not obvious in the code what variables that will be created. It can cause unexpected side effects if you're not careful. Just fetch the values you need directly from the array: `$row['sr_no']` etc.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Magnus Eriksson: Can you please explain what kind of side effect there could be while using extract($row)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add at the top `$balance` to initialize the data first and use it inside `while` rather than `$opening` balance.

```php
$balance = $opening_balance;
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM patty_cash WHERE month(date) = '11' AND year(date) = '2020' ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   extract($row);
   $balance = $balance + $credit - $debit; 
   echo "<tr>
          <td>$sr_no</td>
          <td>$description</td>
          <td>$debit</td>
          <td>$credit</td>
          <td>$balance</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Comment: I add at the top $balance for initialize first data. And use it inside while rather than $opening balance.

Comment: I meant add the explanation to the answer.

Comment: and for SQL efficiency, `\`date\` BETWEEN '2020-11-01' AND LAST_DAY('2020-11-01')`. Ensure there's an index on `date`.